# Automatically insert characters based on selected Word style

Tags: microsoft-word, styles

Straight to the point. Is there any possibility, preferably without scripting, to use the styles in word to insert characters in the beginning and the end of the style?

For example, say I have created a style called "Quote", then I want everything in this style to be within quotation marks. I do not want to write the quotation marks manually if I later decide to e.g. change quotation mark or use different symbols. I want them to be a part of the style.

I hope my explanation is clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is "No".

You could get a specified character at *one end* of a paragraph by setting up a multilevel list level with the Numbering set to "(none)", the character you want in the "Enter formatting for number" box, making a few other suitable settings in that dialog and associating the format with a paragraph style. But I assume that's not enough.

Other than that, it depends.

The only thing I can think of that might allow you to enter paragraphs and easily change the quotation marks later, without code, would be to use content controls (Windows Word only).

e.g. insert a control that is mapped to the document's data store ( e.g. use Insert->Quick Parts->Document Property->Company Fax), then a rich text content control, then another copy of the Company Fax control (or a different one if you might need different characters at the beginning and end of the text).

Mark the two Company Fax controls as uneditable.

Select the three controls and group them.

You can then make copies of that group and type in the middle control.

You would need one editable copy of the Company Fax control somewhere to allow you to set the character you want.

That would allow you to change all the start and end characters by modifying the contents of a single content control.

What it would *not* allow is for you to create your paragraphs, then go through and decide that (for example) paras 1, 3 and 5 should be surrounded by " " and paras 2 and 4 by ' '.

Comment: Unlucky me. Thanks for the reply though :)

Answer (score 0):

You can add characters to every instance of a style using Find-Replace. In the Find and Replace window, add the style to the **Find what** box. In the **Replace with** box select 'Find What Text' from the Special drop down (or use the code ^&). Now you can add characters to the start or end of all text formattted in the style you have chosen.

For instance, to add quotation marks you would type: "^&"

Answer (score 0):

You could make the style include a bullet and use a quote icon as the bullet.  That would put a quote symbol at the beginning of text but not end, which seems to be an acceptable quote design style on the web these days.